# Notation question (shorthand for dot products?)

Tags: analysis, notation, physics

I am reading a paper and trying to understand a calculation and all of a sudden I bump into the following term:

$D^2_y p(t,y(t,x))(\partial_t y(t,x),y^\epsilon(t,x))$

where $p$ is a scalar field (pressure), $D_y^2p$ is the Hessian matrix of $p$ wrt the spacial variables, $y$ and $y^\epsilon$ are vector fields, and $\partial_t y$ is the partial derivative of $y$ wrt $t$.

Now, for understanding the calculations I am assuming that the brackets are notation for:

$\left(D^2_y p(t,y(t,x))\cdot\partial_t y(t,x) \right) \cdot y^\epsilon(t,x))$

This makes sense in many ways, specially since this term ought to be a scalar.

I think I get a confirmation further on in the paper where it is stated that

$D^2_y p (t,y) \left((v \cdot \nabla )y, y^\epsilon-y \right)=\sum_{ijk} \partial^2_{ij}p(t,y) \: v_k \: \partial_k y_i \: (y^\epsilon-y)_j$,

here $v$ is a (velocity) vector field.

**My question is: has anybody seen something like this before?** Maybe its a notation physicists use. I have never seen it before and I couldn't find it anywhere. So far I couldn't think of any other interpretation (nor I think any other is possible). However, I am having trouble following the author's calculations and maybe this could be the source of my problem.

By the way, the paper I am referring to is the following one: http://math1.unice.fr/~brenier/fichiers.ps.pageperso/cms-semigeo-xz-rigorous.pdf

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: **What** paper? $\phantom{}$

Comment: This one: http://math1.unice.fr/~brenier/fichiers.ps.pageperso/cms-semigeo-xz-rigorous.pdf   the first term is on page 4.

Comment: Please include that link into your question.

Comment: I think it may help to include the specific equation (as I believe you made a typo) (page 4):

$$I_{3}=-\int_{D} [(\partial_{t} \nabla p^{\ast} )(t,y(t,x)) \cdot y^{\epsilon}(t,x)
+(D_{y}^{2}p^{\ast})(t,y(t,x))(\partial_{t}y(t,x),y^{\epsilon}(t,x)) ]dx$$
Note that:
$p$ is an implicit function defined $p=p(t,x)$ for the pressure field, $y=y(t,x)\in R^{d}$ is the "vector-valued forcing term", $D$ is a smooth bounded domain in $R^{d}$ $(d=2,3)$, and $\epsilon$ and $\alpha$ (both greater than $0$) are scaling factors.

I believe $\partial$ and $\nabla$ have traditional definitions in this context.

Comment: There is also two other integral terms in $I_{3}$, which makes the full definition of $I_{3}$ read:

$$I_{3}=-\int_{D} [(\partial_{t} \nabla p^{\ast} )(t,y(t,x)) \cdot y^{\epsilon} (t,x)+(D_{y}^{2}p^{\ast})(t,y(t,x))(\partial_{t}y(t,x),y^{\epsilon} (t,x)) ]dx
-\int_{D}(\nabla p^{\ast})(t,y(t,x)) \cdot G(x,y^{\epsilon}(t,x)) dx+I_{5}$$

$$I_{5}=\int_{D} x \cdot (v^{\epsilon}(t,x) \cdot \nabla)y^{\epsilon}(t,x) dx$$

$G(x,y)$ is a given smooth vector-valued source term $D \times R^{d} \to R^{d}$ and $v=v(t,x)\in R^{d}$ is the velocity field, and $x \in D$.

Comment: Yes, well, in fact I replaced the Legendre transform $p^*$ by $p$ on purpose just because I think it doesn't make any difference in the context of my question, and I didn't want it to look overcomplicated. Thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: I wasn't aware if it made any difference or not--I do not understand these equations. However, I provided the full thing in hopes of making things more easily referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Hessian is being treated as a [bilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form); see for instance [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=oNvFAzQXBhsC&pg=PA604&lpg=PA604&dq=%22hessian%20as%20a%20bilinear%20form%22&source=bl&ots=Av5p9D5Qli&sig=2l6PdVlgQwwutXeLP9HEVVSd9_8&hl=de&sa=X&ei=9aKQT-GDEIrCtAbhoPyXBA&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22hessian%20as%20a%20bilinear%20form%22&f=false), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24070/why-can-we-think-of-the-second-fundamental-form-as-a-hessian-matrix) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34799/index-of-a-morse-function-via-the-hessian-tensor).

If so, your interpretation in terms of products is correct (though it's slightly unusual to denote the product of the matrix $D^2_yp$ and the vector $\partial_t y$ with a dot).

Comment: Thank you. So it is exactly what I thought it was. I had never seen this notation used before.

Comment: @mathscat: Neither had I (and I'm a physicist). You're welcome.